# Enum or int to represent payment frequency

Tags: java, enums

So I've got the following class..

```
public abstract class Insurance {
    private int yearlyPremium;
    ...
}
```

and I want a field that represents how often one has to pay for the insurance, either by an enum or an int.

Here's my idea for the enum:

```
public enum PaymentFrequency {
    MONTHLY("Monthly", 12),
    QUARTERLY("Quarterly", 4),
    SEMIANNUALLY("Semiannually", 2),
    ANNUALLY("Annually", 1);

    private String name;
    private int paymentsPerYear;

    PaymentFrequency(String name, int paymentsPerYear) {
        this.name = name;
        this.paymentsPerYear = paymentsPerYear;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public int getPaymentsPerYear() {
        return paymentsPerYear;
    }
}
```

An added advantage to the enum is that I can use its `values` (static) and `getName` methods to generate dropdown menus for the user interface, so that if I add a new `PaymentFrequency`, I will not have to change the dropdown menu whatsoever.

Is this a job for an enum, or am I being overly complicated here? The field could be represented by a simple int, but the downside is that I'd have to check if it's a valid number, as I only want values between 1 and 12 (both inclusive) so that `12 % n == 0`.

Comment: This is great use of enum; run with it! I'd pick a different name for the getName() method though, since it's so similar to the enum's built-in name() method. Maybe getDisplayName(). Or if you want to prepare for the day when your app hits the international market, you can look up the display name from a properties file using the enum name as part of the key.

Comment: I would say go for Enum. I think your enum will handle all your cases which you would otherwise have to handle in your code

Comment: The thing about enums constants is that they are compile time constants. You should ideally be using a data store unless you want to modify,compile and deploy your code every time a new payment frequency is introduced.

Comment: Go for you Enum solution :-) but you probably don't want to expose the enum name (at least not directly) in a UI, since translation can become an issue, but that dependa of course on your use case. Just something you might want to consider

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One of the signs of bad code is magic numbers. Numbers that appear in your code, but are not documented why the number is there(Why is this a 12 instead of 11?).

Enums are almost always more than you need, but they are almost always the right choice. If you need to add functionality to this class, it is really easy to do that. It would be really easy to create a method `public Date getNextPaymentDate(Date lastPaymentDate)`.

Having a class that is easy to expand makes your code easier to maintain.